# Select FROM syntax multiple tables Oracle 11G

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Hi there I have multiple tables which I extract data. I have a question regarding the syntax for ORACLE 11 g  I have used SQL server before .

My Query looks like this

```
FROM 
dw_bi.dw_detalle_altas
let join dw_bi.dm_producto_claro
```

is the first part before the period dw_bi the schema ? object? and the second part dw_detalle_altas and dm_producto_claro the table?

Comment: No idea what you are asking here. But you missed a `f` in `let`

Comment: The first part is schema, the second part can be `view` or `table`.

Comment: For production code it is generally best to avoid hardcoding schema names.

Comment: The question title is about the syntax for querying multiple tables (you'll probably need a join), but the actual question seems to be about [database object name resolution](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements009.htm).

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements008.htm), the term before the dot is the schema, and the term after the dot is the table.  So, in general, your query would look like:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourSchema.table1 t2
LEFT JOIN yourSchema.table2 t2
    ON -- some conditions
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Left outer join or inner join to fetch data from multiple tables.

Left Outer join:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 AS T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 AS T2
ON T1.column_name = T2.column_name;
```

Inner Join:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 AS T1
INNER JOIN table2 AS T2
ON T1.column_name = T2.column_name;
```

Comment: Correct, though perhaps worth mentioning that the `inner` and `outer` keywords are optional.